# Place a picture under a DIV and align it horizontally based on the DIV width

Tags: html, css

I'd like the picture to be placed under the green container (**and** aligned horizontally based on the width of the green container). How could I achieve that?
Many thanks,

See http://jsfiddle.net/29cz81du/

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="carte-des-soins">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-1">Visage</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-2">Epilation</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-3">Mains</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-4">Pieds</a></span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-5">Corps</a></span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="container-des-soins">
  <div id="soins-1" class="textzone">
    <div class="desc-box clearfix">
      <p class="desc-box-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-267-204-7.jpg"> 
    </div>
    <div class="carte clearfix">
      <div class="desc-soins">
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Equilibre&nbsp;</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : toute peau à équilibrer (grasse, mixte ou sèche). Soin du visage traditionnel, personnalisé selon le type de peau, qui vous fera retrouver une peau saine et un teint éclatant.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Pureté active</strong>

          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux grasses ou mixtes comédogènes. Soin spécifique visant à assainir le teint, éliminer les comédons et aider à réguler les excès de sébum. Ce soin s’effectue, de préférence par cure de 4 soins avec l’application au préalable
          d’une crème spécifique pendant quelques jours.&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Aqua Phyt's
</strong>
          <br>75 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Soin très hydratant à l'Acide Hyaluronique d'origine végétale&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>PHYT'S : soin visage Capyl
</strong>
          <br>60 min.&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Type de peaux : peaux sèches à rougeurs diffuses, sensibles, fines. Soin calmant et décongestionnant, spécialement conçu pour les peaux sensibles ou à rougeurs diffuses.&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CARTE DES SOINS */
#carte-des-soins {

  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
  list-style: none;
        padding:0;

}
#carte-des-soins li {
display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: red;

}

#carte-des-soins li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #474032;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}



#container-des-soins {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
#soins-1,
#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4,
#soins-5 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
      margin-top: 30px;

  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1px;
}

#soins-2,
#soins-3,
#soins-4,
#soins-5 {
  display: none;
}
#soins-2 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#soins-1 p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#soins-1 a {
  color: #3A7CDB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#soins-1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.carte p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.carte {
  float: right;
  width: 55%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.desc-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}
.desc-box-text {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.desc-soins {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.type-de-soins {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;  
    z-index: 4;
  width: 179px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.desc-soins strong {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* END CARTE DES SOINS */
```

Comment: You mean in addition to the pic you have already in there? Namely, one *outside* the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the green box HTML from this:

```
<div class="desc-box clearfix">
  <p class="desc-box-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-267-204-7.jpg"> 
</div>
```

To this

```
<div class="desc-box clearfix">
  <div class="green">
  <p class="desc-box-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-267-204-7.jpg">
  </div>
  <img class="type-de-soins" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-267-204-7.jpg" style="width:204px;display:block;margin:0 auto;"> 
</div>
```

You'll be wrapping the content in your column so that the green is around the desired area.  I inlined the style for the image to use the width, block, margin as auto setup for centering.

Then, modify the CSS to this for `.desc-box` and you'll get your desired result, assuming I understand it properly.

```
.desc-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
.desc-box>.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/29cz81du/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want to keep one picture inside the green DIV. How can I remove it? (if I simply remove the picture path from the code it creates collateral impact). Many thanks

Comment: Remove the `float` from `.desc-box-text` (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/29cz81du/2/)).  Floating really shouldn't be used as the end-all-be-all of design.  In fact, you should rarely use it.  Look into designing using the `display` CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using another DIV container for the image and putting all those divs (image div included) into a table. And putting an `align-content='center'` into your css to the table rows. Hope it helps

Another better solution is containing both divs (the red div and the image div) into another div and you can apply the CSS that you want to use for centering

Comment: Please do not use tables for design... it's like going back in time 10 years.